# how to get AWS quicksight to show the old and new value of a particular column of a table (for comparison purposes)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

what I have seen so far is that the aws glue crawler creates the table based on the latest changes in the s3 files.
let's say crawler creates a table and then I upload a CSV with updated values in one column. the crawler is run again and it updates the table's column with the updated values. I want to be able to show a comparison of the old and new data in quick sight eventually, is this scenario possible?
for example,
right now my csv file is set up as details of one aws service, like RDS is the csv file name and the columns are account id, account name, what region is it in, etc etc
there was one column of percentage with a value 50%, it gets updated with 70%. would I be able to somehow get the old value as well to show in quicksight, to say like previously it was 50% and now its 70%

Maybe this scenerio is not even valid? because I want to be able to show like what account has what cost in xyz month and show how the cost is different in other months. If I make separate tables on each update of csv then there would be 1000+ tables at one point.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you are aiming to track data over time.  Above you suggest creating a table for each time series, why not instead maintain a record in a table for each time series, you can then create various Analysis over the data, comparing specific months or tracking month-by-month values.

Comment: I did not understand you saying "maintain a record in a table for each time series" can you please elaborate more on this?
Like one table having different data based on time? can we even do something like that?